# Setup eclipse java SE-1.7

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, ide

I wanted to start learning java but Eclipse is giving me some trouble.

First of all I'm a beginner with Java with little to no knowledge about it. I want to use 'JavaSe-1.7'. I have no clear reason to use it besides using the latest version. After downloading Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers) I created a new Java project and selected 'use an execution eviorment JRE : JavaSE-1.7'. This directly popped the notification saying 'The default compiler compliance level for the current workspace is 1.6. The new project will use a project specific compiler compliance level of 1.7.'. I finished creating the project and started following some tutorials.

However I noticed directly I have 2 errors which dont explain anything or have a source. I ignored it and started typing and tried to import 'java.io.console' however it said 'The import java.io cannot be resolved' and I have no idea what is the cause of it neither how to fix this.

Would like some instructions into the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide the exact source code that's giving you trouble.

Comment: hm, did you try to install JavaSE-1.6 as well? Because the JRE can be installed all side by side, so I suggest to just do it if Eclipse says that it was expecting it. Even if I agree to just use latest, I would try that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not have your JDK/JRE set up correctly.

Check the following:

- Did you install a JDK or just the JSE? The JDK is needed to compile .java files to .class files. Without it, you can only **run** java programs, not develop them. If not, download and install it from Oracle website.
- Check in Eclipse, if you have the JRE installed there as well. You just need to specify the path to the installation. You can reach this screen via the "Window->Prefrences" menu. see this screenshot:

[image]

The message you receive about project specific compiler compliance level is not a problem, it just means that your workspace is set up to comply to java 1.6 but your project will comply to java 1.7 standards. Also, Java 7 in general is no problem whatsoever.

Paths may differ, especially if you're not running a *nix OS. Just point the location to where you installed your JDK.

Answer (score 5):

Check your Eclipse preferences: Java -> Installed JREs. The one that you're using should be marked and it should be a JDK not just a JRE.

Also check your project's build path: Right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path 
Check in the "libraries" folder whether the JRE System Library is present and if not add it using "Add library"->"JRE System Library" and then select the correct one (from an installed JDK).