# Java multi catch exceptions errors

Tags: java, exception

I've checked this code several times and I cannot figure out why it's spitting back errors in regards to the catch statement. I'm aware that handling multiple exception with one catch clause is possible with Java 7.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MultiCatch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number;

        try
        {
            File file = new File("Numbers.txt");
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                number = inputFile.nextInt();

                System.out.println(number);
            }

            inputFile.close();
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error processing the file.");
            //System.out.println("Error processing the file." + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
$ javac MultiCatch.java
MultiCatch.java:25: <identifier> expected
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                   ^
MultiCatch.java:25: '{' expected
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                     ^
MultiCatch.java:25: not a statement
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                                             ^
MultiCatch.java:25: ';' expected
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                                              ^
MultiCatch.java:31: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
5 errors
```

If it makes a difference I'm on a OSX 10.8 running Java 7.

Comment: Your JRE is may be Java 7, but you are likely compiling under Java 6 though.  The first error is expecting an identifier which would indicate it is looking for `catch(FileNotFoundException ex)` which is allowed under java 6 spec.

Comment: @CsabaToth I'm compiling my code with the command line interface.

Comment: Try doing `javac -version` before compiling your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Java 6, I get this compiler error with your code:

```
C:\dev\src\misc\MultiCatch.java:25: <identifier> expected
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                   ^
C:\dev\src\misc\MultiCatch.java:25: '{' expected
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                     ^
C:\dev\src\misc\MultiCatch.java:25: not a statement
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                                             ^
C:\dev\src\misc\MultiCatch.java:25: ';' expected
        catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
                                                               ^
C:\dev\src\misc\MultiCatch.java:31: reached end of file while parsing
}
```

However, under Java 7, your code compiles successfully.

You must have been using Java 6 or below to get those errors.

The problem is *not* that each exception must have a name.  Under Java 7,

```
catch(FileNotFoundException | InputMismatchException ex)
```

is correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This code has no errors and is Java 7 compliant. Check the settings of your compiler, you are compiling the code as Java 6.

Comment: For the configurationally challenged like me: You can get this error when running Javadoc, too. For Eclipse/Windows change the javadoc command from ``C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin\javadoc.exe`` to ``C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javadoc.exe``

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IDE set the Java compatibility level from 1.6 or 1.5 to 7.

1. For Eclipse this applies to OSX too: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328328/setup-eclipse-java-se-1-7). I'm using Eclipse, and it's one thing to specify which JVM/JRE/JDK will run your program, but it can run your program in different Java versions.
2. For NetBeans look at these: [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk7.html), [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDKVersionAndMacOS), project level settings maybe necessary too.
3. IntelliJ: Set the project level to 7: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699321/using-intellij-to-compile-java-7-configuration-trouble).